# How to pass dynamic parameter to Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a look up activity which retrives data from table and then I need to pass that data to a azure function using azure function activity.

```
LOOKUP --> AZUREFUNCTION
```

I am passing the below in the body of the azure function since it is a POST method

```
@Activity('lookup1).output.value
```

But the pipeline fails. At the same time if I hardcode the value in body, pipeline executes.

Can you help me with how to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Can you show the details of the error? On my side it is no problem. Do you return json object?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the details of the error you get?

On my side it is no problem.

This is the setting of my lookup activity:

[image]

And this is the setting of my function activity:

[image]

MY azure function is written by C# script:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static JObject Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string a = "{'test':'123'}";
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(a);
    return json;
}
```

It works fine:

[image]

Comment: hi!
i want to send following json in body
{"name":"@activity('lookupSupplierCodes').output.firstRow.Prop_3"}
but the values "@activity('lookupSupplierCodes').output.firstRow.Prop_3" is sent as string can you help with this?